# Should a matchmaker be in tcp or udp?

Tags: networking, multiplayer

I wrote a game server in udp, now I don't know if the matchmaker be in tcp or udp.
Because I know udp is connectionless and I think the matchmaker should be in tcp because they will connect to each other .

Comment: Why don't you try that and see if there are issues with it?

Comment: I think I will with udp and if it work I continue with it . and thank you man every question I ask you are the first to answer I appreciate it :)